# Remote svg image .NET MAUI

Tags: maui

I can't display remote svg images in `<Image>` control.

Example:

When I try to display [this image](https://www.meteosuisse.admin.ch/static/product/resources/weather-symbols/120.svg), I don't see anything.

```xml
<Image Source="https://www.meteosuisse.admin.ch/static/product/resources/weather-symbols/120.svg" />
```

It's the same with [this image](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics#/media/Fichier:SVG_Logo.svg)

```xml
<Image Source="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics#/media/File:SVG_Logo.svg" />
```

But if I only change the url of the image with [this one](https://aka.ms/campus.jpg) which is of type JPG, everything works

```xml
<Image Source="https://aka.ms/campus.jpg" />
```

Am I doing something wrong?

.NET MAUI Version: 6.0.548
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64 bits) - Current
Version 17.4.3

Best Regards

Tested on

- Windows (net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0)
- Android (net6.0-android)

I have see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71947907/dot-net-maui-image-control-not-showing-remote-source) but here, the problem is only with SVG remote image.

Comment: MAUI's image control does not natively support SVG.  If you add a SVG to the project at build time the tooling will convert it to a PNG for you.  You will need to use a third party control for runtime SVG support

Comment: Just want to add. Even in your application, you should not be using SVG in the resources. It will work on android, but the moment you decide to build for IOS you will have to change it everywhere to PNG.

Comment: @H.A.H. - *"not be using SVG in the resources."*  That might confuse people. An .svg resource [with buildaction `MauiImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/image?view=net-maui-7.0#load-a-local-image) is automatically converted to appropriate platform-specific .png(s).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I meant that you have to access your resources with *.png, not *.svg, even if it *.svg file behind it. (So you do not have problems with IOS.)

Comment: I found a solution that can be used. It's not ideal but it works.
I am using a WebView like this. `<WebView Source="{Binding Meteo.current.weather_symbol_id, StringFormat='https://www.meteosuisse.admin.ch/static/product/resources/weather-symbols/{0}.svg'}" />`

Comment: @piferrari You can post this solution as an answer, it will help more people.

Comment: @Dongzhi Wang-MSFT That's not really a solution to the question. Rather a workaround...

Answer (score 0):

I made this. It doesnt load from a URL but it does load SVG data as a string ("<svg ..... "): https://gist.github.com/andressbarajas/c2248d5925087f5b769aacb9af8f74a8

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml.Linq;

using SkiaSharp.Views.Maui;
using SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls;
using SKSvg = SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg;

namespace Project.Views;

public class SvgImage : SKCanvasView
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _color_mappings = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public static BindableProperty SourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Source), typeof(string), typeof(SvgImage), default(string), propertyChanged: OnPropertyChanged);

    public string Source
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(SourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(SourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static BindableProperty ColorMappingProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ColorMapping), typeof(string), typeof(SvgImage), default(string), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.Default, propertyChanged: OnPropertyChanged);

    public string ColorMapping
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(ColorMappingProperty);
        set => SetValue(ColorMappingProperty, value);
    }

    public SvgImage()
    {
        BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
    }

    protected override void OnPaintSurface(SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnPaintSurface(args);

        try
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Content))
            {
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Content)))
                {
                    if (stream == null)
                        throw new Exception("SVG Stream is NULL for Content");

                    CreateSVG(stream, args);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("An error occured when reading the Svg Resource: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void CreateSVG(Stream stream, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            var canvas = args.Surface.Canvas;
            canvas.Clear();

            var svg = new SKSvg();

            // Clear all mappings
            _color_mappings.Clear();

            // Populate mappings
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ColorMapping))
            {
                var mappings = ColorMapping.Split(';');
                foreach (var map in mappings)
                {
                    var key_and_value = map.Split('=');
                    _color_mappings.Add(key_and_value[0], key_and_value[1]);
                }
            }

            if (_color_mappings.Count > 0)
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    var svg_xml = XDocument.Load(sr);

                    var fill_color_elements = svg_xml.Root.Descendants().Where(x => x.Attribute("fill") != null).ToList();
                    foreach (var element in fill_color_elements)
                    {
                        var key = element.Attribute("fill").Value;
                        if (_color_mappings.ContainsKey(key))
                            element.Attribute("fill").Value = _color_mappings[key];
                    }

                    var style_elements = svg_xml.Root.Descendants().Where(x => x.Attribute("style") != null).ToList();
                    foreach (var element in style_elements)
                    {
                        var style_key = element.Attribute("style").Value;
                        var keys = style_key.Split(';');

                        for (var i = 0; i < keys.Count(); i++)
                        {
                            if (keys[i].Contains("fill"))
                            {
                                var key_split = keys[i].Split("fill:");
                                if (_color_mappings.ContainsKey(key_split[1]))
                                {
                                    keys[i] = "fill:" + _color_mappings[key_split[1]];
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        element.Attribute("style").Value = String.Join(';', keys);
                    }

                    using (var mem_stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        svg_xml.Save(mem_stream);
                        mem_stream.Position = 0;
                        svg.Load(mem_stream);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                stream.Position = 0;
                svg.Load(stream);
            }

            var info = args.Info;
            canvas.Translate(info.Width / 2f, info.Height / 2f);

            var bounds = svg.ViewBox;
            float xRatio = info.Width / bounds.Width;
            float yRatio = info.Height / bounds.Height;

            var ratio = Math.Min(xRatio, yRatio);

            canvas.Scale(ratio);
            canvas.Translate(-bounds.MidX, -bounds.MidY);
            canvas.DrawPicture(svg.Picture);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("An error occured when reading the Svg Resource: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        InvalidateSurface();
    }

    private static void OnPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var skCanvasView = bindable as SKCanvasView;
        skCanvasView?.InvalidateSurface();
    }

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();

        InvalidateSurface();
    }

    protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

        InvalidateSurface();
    }
}
```